# If $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a nilpotent matrix then $A$ is similar to $2A$

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence, similar-matrices

If $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a nilpotent matrix then $A$ is similar to $2A$
I am trying to prove this property but the truth is I cannot find how to express the matrix $ P $ such that $$ A=P^{-1}2AP \Leftrightarrow PA =2AP$$

I tried a diagonal matrix but it didn't get me anywhere, can someone help me?

Comment: Begin with the simplest case.  Say $A = [0,1;0,0]$.

Comment: Do you know Jordan normal form?

Comment: No i don't know

Comment: @arreflay2019: Do you know that a matrix is always similar to an upper triangular matrix?